# how to add class to a span inside a div when the div is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to add a class to a span that is inside a div when the div is clicked.
I have many divs and spans with the same class name

```
$('.menu_item_conteiner').click(function() {
$('.menu_item_conteiner').removeClass("tab_selected");
  $(this).addClass('tab_selected');

  // This add a class to the last span and not the one is inside of the clicked div.
  // $(".menu_item_conteiner span:last").addClass("show_element");

});
```

HTML

```
 <span class="menu_item_conteiner">
   <span class="menu_item">
     Text
  </span>
  <span class="menu_imagen_icon">
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: The element that you are adding the class to is defined in your `$()`. So `show_element` is being added to the last span, or this: `$("#menu_item_conteiner span:last")`

Comment: Probably need to use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/), like `$(this).find('span')`. Can you provide a piece of HTML?

Comment: You seem to be confusing IDs and classes.

Comment: @AlbertDrew You need to show your HTML structure, and explain which span you want to change, so we can help you properly.

Comment: In fact all  are span and classes, but I thought it would be confusing to say span inside a span when the outside span is clicked

Comment: There are two spans inside the container, which do you want to add the class to?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the code for your task:

```
$('.menu_item_conteiner').click(function() {
   $('span.menu_item').removeClass('yourClassName');
   $(this).find('span.menu_item').addClass('yourClassName');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
$('.menu_item_conteiner').click(function() {
   var d = document.getElementById("span");
   d.className = d.className + " otherclass";
}
```

or:

```
$('.menu_item_conteiner').click(function() {
   var d = document.getElementById("span");
   d.addClass( 'some_other_class' );
}
```

This would add the class to the span called span.

Comment: `span` probably isn't an ID, it's a tag name.

Comment: I know that was just a place holder

Comment: Thank you Gabriel but what if I have many copies of this divs and spans with the same class name?

Comment: Sorry I know this was confusing. Thanks for your help everyone :)